# I am struggling to replace stringA in a column Description with stringB if stringA contains stringC

Tags: r, gsub

id,Description

```
1,DRIVING VEHICLE ON HIGHWAY WITHOUT CURRENT REGISTRATION PLATES AND VALIDATION TABS

2,EXCEEDING SPEED LIMIT IN SCHOOL ZONE WITH  35 MPH IN 25 ZONE

3,DRIVING VEHICLE IN EXCESS OF REASONABLE AND PRUDENT SPEED ON HIGHWAY 8855
```

If I want to replace whole Description row with "EXCESS SPEED" if it contains "SPEED".
I am using gsub function :

```
training_data$Description = gsub("(dot)(star)SPEED(dot)(star)","EXCESS SPEED",training_data$Description,fixed = TRUE)
```

It is still not working I am getting result (just replacing "SPEED" with "EXCESS SPEED" instead of the entire row) :

Output Received:

```
id,Description

1,DRIVING VEHICLE ON HIGHWAY WITHOUT CURRENT REGISTRATION PLATES AND VALIDATION TABS

2,EXCEEDING EXCESS SPEED LIMIT IN SCHOOL ZONE WITH  35 MPH IN 25 ZONE

3,DRIVING VEHICLE IN EXCESS OF REASONABLE AND PRUDENT EXCESS SPEED ON HIGHWAY 8855
```

Expected Output:

```
id,Description

1,DRIVING VEHICLE ON HIGHWAY WITHOUT CURRENT REGISTRATION PLATES AND VALIDATION TABS

2,EXCESS SPEED

3,EXCESS SPEED
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
training_data$Description = sapply(training_data[,2],function(sentence){

  if(grepl("SPEED",sentence)){
    as.character("EXCESS SPEED")
  }else{
    as.character(sentence)
  }
})
```

Comment: I think that is a bit over-complicated. `replace(training_data$Description,  grepl("SPEED",training_data$Description), "EXCESS SPEED")` or similar will do it. Or even `training_data$Description[grepl("SPEED",training_data$Description)] <- "EXCESS SPEED"` if you're overwriting data.

Comment: training_data$Description[grepl("SPEED",training_data$Description)] <- "EXCESS SPEED"

Thanks a lot! It works :)